# How to alter SQL return array to a value and return to the front-end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I want to make a judge button to judge the value entering from users whether the users used or not. But I faced some problem , I want to count the value when I got return data from the database with knex SQL Builder, I found the return data was [ { 'count(`Program_Codename`)': 1 }].
How can I get the value only count number ?

this is my backend code:

```js
router.post('/',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.Program_name);
     db('program_detail').count('Program_Codename').where('Program_Codename',req.body.Program_name).asCallback(function(err,values){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(values);
            if(values > 0){
                res.json({success:1});
                //console.log(req.body.Program_name);
                console.log("This Program_Codename has already been used.")
                
            }else{
                console.log("This Program_Codename can be used.")
            }
        }
        db.destroy();
     });
    
});

module.exports = router;
```

Moreover, I want to return the judgement to the front-end website to tell users the results with ajax , how can I do ?

this is my front-end ajax code:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#checkname_btn").click(function(){
       console.log("test");
       var Program_name = { Program_name : $(':input[name=Program_Codename]').val()};
       
       $.ajax({
                data: Program_name,
                url: '/check',
                dataType: 'json',
                type:'post',
                cache: false,
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data){
                    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);  
                }
            });

         //$(':input[name=Program_Codename]').next().next().after('<div id = "id" align="center">'+message+'</div>');
         //$(':input[name=Program_Codename]').focus(function(){
         //$('#id').remove();

           return false;
        });

      
   });
```

The comment out code is the outcome I want to make, but I don't know how to do it. I want to make realtime feedback to users under the judge button.

By the way, I can got the value passed from the front-end.

My button code:

```html
 <td class="td-edit">Program/Codename:</td>
                            <td class="td-edit">
                                <input class="form-control-edit" type="text" name="Program_Codename">
                                <br><button class="btn btn-primary" id=checkname_btn>Check Program/Codename</button>
                            </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get count by this code:

```
var count = values[0]['count(Program_Codename)'];
```